# Proving these inequalities for a symmetric random walk

Tags: probability, inequality

I would like to prove the following inequalities. Here $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ where $x_i$ are i.i.d and symmetric.

> $$P(|S_n|>x) \geq \frac{1}{2}P(\max_{k\leq n}|X_k|>x)\geq \frac{1}{2}(1-e^{-nP(|X_i|>x)})$$
>
> $$P(\max_{k\leq n} |S_i|>x)\leq 2P(|S_n|>x)$$

My attempt:

For the first one

$$P(S_n>x) = \sum_{k\leq n} P(S_j<x \text{ for } j<k, S_k>x, S_n-S_k > 0) $$
$$= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k\leq n} P(S_j<x \text{ for } j<k, S_k>x) $$
$$=\frac{1}{2} P(\max_{k<n} S_k > x)$$

I think by symmetry of the random walk, that then gives

$$P(|S_n|>x) \geq \frac{1}{2}P(\max_{k\leq n}|S_k|>x)$$

I am completely stuck on getting from $S_k$ to $X_k$. Further, I don't know how to get to

$$\frac{1}{2}(1-e^{-nP(|X_i|>x)})$$

For the second inequality I believe I need to use the reflection principle in someway. But I have also made no progress towards that one.

Edit:

It just occured to me that:

$$P(\max_{k\leq n}|X_k|>x)=1-P(\max_{k\leq n}|X_k| \leq x)$$
$$=1-P(|X_1| \leq x)^n=1-(1-P(|X_1| > x))^n$$
$$\geq 1-e^{-nP(|X_i|>x)}$$

So I got that part sorted

---

I think I got the first inequality. Basically it goes

$$P(S_n>x) \geq \sum_k P(X_k > x, \sum_{i\neq k}X_i>0, \max_{j<k}|X_j|<x)$$$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_k P(X_k > x,\max_{j<k}|X_j|<x)$$

Doing the same for $P(S_n<-x)$ and then adding gives the result. Can someone confirm this is correct?

---

For the second inequality

Let $A_k = \{ |S_k| > x; S_j < x, j<k\}$

$P(|S_n|>x) =\sum_{k=1}^n P(A_k; sgn(S_n-S_k)=sgn(S_k))$

But here I'm unsure how to get  $\geq$. It seems the latter should be $=\frac{1}{2}...$?

Where the last inequality follows from the fact that